# How to prevent "trust relationship between this machine and domain failed" error from happening when restoring VM from a snapshot?

Tags: windows, active-directory, virtual-machine

When you restore VM (that belongs to a windows domain) from (an old enough) snapshot you'll get this error:

> trust relationship between this machine and domain failed

This happens because domain controller periodically renews computer account password (and maybe few other things).

Is there any way to configure domain controller (or anything else) in such way that this doesn't happen? I don't care about security risks/etc -- all this is in controlled environment.

Comment: btw, solution is to leave domain, join again and reboot. But doing it every time it happens is a problem, especially if snapshot restore is part of automation.

Comment: I believe there's a group policy setting (applied to the VM) to turn off the automatic password changes.  I don't remember what it's called, sorry.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Two solutions:

1. You can try the policy like @Harry mentioned to disable machine password:  
   Reference:  [Domain member: Disable machine account password changes](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj852191(v=ws.11).aspx)

Per the article:  *The Domain member: Disable machine account password* changes policy setting determines whether a domain member periodically changes its computer account password. Setting its value to **Enabled** prevents the domain member from changing the computer account password.  While not recommended for production environments, setting the value to **Enabled** his is what you would set the value at in your controlled environment which would eliminate the identified problem.

2. Another way to handle it is using PowerShell.  This won't prevent it from happening but will solve it, you can put it in a script and use: 
   `Test-ComputerSecureChannel –Server dc -Repair`
    Reference:  [Test-ComputerSecureChannel](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/reference/5.1/microsoft.powershell.management/test-computersecurechannel)

Comment: I'll test #1 and if it works -- mark this as a solution. About #2 -- looks like an interesting solution, but I'd rather not to have the problem to begin with. Thank you

Comment: I rolled back to my 1 month old snapshot today. It worked like a charm. Thank you!

Comment: Still 2017 and it does not work. I try the solution #1 and when the snapshot was reverted, the issue comes again

Answer (score 1):

For those of us using a production domain controller, it's easier to do this on the VMs.

Set this in the registry to [disable automatic machine account password changes](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/154501/how-to-disable-automatic-machine-account-password-changes):
[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\services\Netlogon\Parameters]
"DisablePasswordChange"=dword:00000001

If you ever get "The trust relationship between this workstation and the primary domain failed", one easy fix is to log in as local admin (or a domain account with network disconnected) and use the powershell [Reset-ComputerMachinePassword](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/reset-computermachinepassword?view=powershell-5.1) cmdlet as follows:

```
$credential = Get-Credential
# Enter domain admin account when prompted
Reset-ComputerMachinePassword -Server ClosestDomainControllerNameHere -Credential $credential
```