# System.SystemException: The trust relationship between this workstation and the primary domain failed

Tags: .net, active-directory

we have software Tool on which we are trying to create a windows user as Service Account , to run some of the Services using that userService Account. In one of the machine, we have got the following exception which failed to create an UserAccount .

Error :

```
2022/02/21 10:24:06.276|ERROR|Failed to create Service Account : System.SystemException: The trust relationship between this workstation and the primary domain failed.
at System.Security.Principal.NTAccount.TranslateToSids(IdentityReferenceCollection sourceAccounts, Boolean& someFailed)
at System.Security.Principal.NTAccount.Translate(IdentityReferenceCollection sourceAccounts, Type targetType, Boolean forceSuccess)
at System.Security.Principal.NTAccount.Translate(Type targetType)
at InstallPackage.Models.ServiceAccount.ServiceAccountManager.IsServiceAccountExists(String name)
at InstallPackage.Models.ServiceAccount.ServiceAccountCreateTask.<OperationFunction>d__6.MoveNext() |features|
```

The following is the piece of code related to User Creation.

```
public bool CreateServiceAccount(string userName)
{
var isUserCreated = false;
//create service Account to install and run services
bool userExists = IsServiceAccountExists(userName);
if (userExists)
{
DeleteUser(userName, serviceCredentialsFile);
}
isUserCreated = CreateUser(userName, serviceCredentialsFile);
return isUserCreated;
}
private bool IsServiceAccountExists(string name)
{
bool exists = false;
try
{
NTAccount acct = new NTAccount(name);
SecurityIdentifier id = (SecurityIdentifier)acct.Translate(typeof(SecurityIdentifier));
exists = id.IsAccountSid();
}
catch (IdentityNotMappedException ex)
{
_log.LogError("Invalid user account " + ex.ToString());
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
_log.LogError("Error in verifying the service account exist: " + ex);
}
return exists;
}
private bool CreateUser(string userName, string serviceCredentialsFile)
{
try
{
var encryptedPwd = string.Empty;
string plainPassword = CommonHelper.GetRandomPassword();
encryptedPwd = Crypto.ProtectStringV1(plainPassword);
DirectoryEntry activeDirectory = new DirectoryEntry("WinNT://" +
Environment.MachineName + ",computer");
DirectoryEntry newUser = activeDirectory.Children.Add(userName, "user");
newUser.Invoke("SetPassword", new object[] { plainPassword });
newUser.Invoke("Put", new object[] { "Description", "Service account for Windows Services" });
newUser.CommitChanges();
DirectoryEntry grp;
ServiceAccountStoreSettings serviceAccountCredentialDetails = new ServiceAccountStoreSettings
{
UserName = userName,
EncryptedPassword = encryptedPwd
};
var protectedJsonData = Protect.ProtectSettingFile(JsonSerializer.Serialize(serviceAccountCredentialDetails));
File.WriteAllText(serviceCredentialsFile, protectedJsonData);
var UsersGroup = WindowsGroupPermissionsManager.GetGroupByName(
WindowsGroupPermissionsManager.USERS_GROUP_NAME, WindowsGroupPermissionsManager.USERS_GROUP_DESC);
// add ServiceUser to Group
AddUserToGroups(activeDirectory, newUser,UsersGroup.Name);
var principalContext = new PrincipalContext(ContextType.Machine);
var performanceMonitorGroup = GroupPrincipal.FindByIdentity(principalContext, "Performance Monitor Users");
// add ServiceUser to Performance Monitor Users Group
AddUserToGroups(activeDirectory ,newUser,performanceMonitorGroup.Name);
var performanceLogUsersGroup = GroupPrincipal.FindByIdentity(principalContext, "Performance Log Users");
// add ServiceUser to Performance Log Users Group
AddUserToGroups(activeDirectory ,newUser,performanceLogUsersGroup.Name);
_log.LogInformation("Account Created Successfully");
GrantLogonAsServiceRight(userName);
return true;
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
_log.LogError("unable to create user Account", ex.ToString());
return false;
}
}
```

Comment: Run this Powershell command as a domain administrator `Test-ComputerSecureChannel -Repair`. This is not a .Net issue, the machine has lost credentials to the domain (machines actually have their own users also, and this password has been lost). Make sure the system time is correct before doing so

Comment: By the way, most of those objects you are creating need to be disposed with `using`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to prevent "trust relationship between this machine and domain failed" error from happening when restoring VM from a snapshot?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42592041/how-to-prevent-trust-relationship-between-this-machine-and-domain-failed-error)